# Any Mapping using Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, any

Nhibernate documentation specfies `ReferenceAny()` as a method to do the mapping inheritance trees.

[Check doc here](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping#Any). However the code specifies the method as deprecated and will be removed in the next versions. Is there any other way to map this.

Comment: I am using Nhibernate version  3.1.0.4000 and Fluent version 1.2.0.712

Comment: What do the entities you're trying to reference look like?  Can you just use Reference()?  AFAIK <any> mapping is for when your entities are related (or not) in a way that NH's built-in inheritance strategies can't support

Answer (score 0):

Only the `ReferencesAny<TOther>(Member property)` overload has been deprecated.  `ReferencesAny<TOther>(Expression<Func<T,TOther>> memberExpression)` is still perfectly valid.

It's the same type of confusion as when people claim that `Enum.ToString` has been deprecated.  The overloads that take an `IFormatProvider` have been deprecated, but the other `ToString` overloads are fine.  The problem is that Intellisense shows the member stricken-out, even though only a subset of its overloads are actually obsolete.

For more information on using `ReferencesAny` in Fluent NHibernate, see my other answer: [Mapping to multiple tables with Fluent nHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989279/mapping-to-multiple-tables-with-fluent-nhibernate/8990435#8990435)