# Mapping to multiple tables with Fluent nHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

Here's my situation..
Suppose you have the following model entities, which represent single tables on their own:

**Movies** [ Movie_Id, Title, Rating, .. ]
**Actors** [ Actor_Id, FirstName, LastName, .. ]
**Director** [ Director_Id, FirstName, LastName, .. ]

And another entity/table called "Recommendations", which represents recommendations between users within a website. The idea is that a recommendation could be of any type, i.e. someone recommending an actor, or someone recommending a movie. Basically, the table should look something like this:

**Recommendations** [ Recommendation_Id, Object_Id, Object_Type, .. ]

And here's what i'm stuck into. How can I map these relationships in nHibernate with Fluent?
I mean.. while mapping, I can't specify the Type (which table related to) 'cause that's determined on runtime, but I can't rely only on the Id 'cause by itself it cannot imply to which table belongs to.
For instance, imagine this record on Recommendations table:
Recommendation_Id--Object_Id--Object_Type
83001--4010123---"M"
Basically I'm storing a char identifier (in this case "M" stands for table "Movies") to know to which table Object_Id belongs to. I cannot just store Object_Id without Object_Type..

As final comments, I'd like to add that I've seen all the table-per-class, table-per-subclass, table-per-concrete-class examples, but I believe none of these fits in this situation, as Movies_Id, Actors_Id, Directors_Id, ... are all different between them, so is Recommendations_Id. I mean, there's no base class-child class inheritance here, they don't share Id's at all..

I hope I make myself clear.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be noted that fluent nHibernate does not currently support many-to-any which is what I thought this would do.  Unless I'm wrong, saving a recommendation when you update a movie won't happen seamlessly.  Daniel's answer was closer to just about anything else I could find tho ;o)

Comment: If you want to map the other side of the `any` relationship, as in `Movie.Recommendations`, I believe you could do this with a `one-to-many` and a `where="Object_Type='M'"` attribute on the collection, which you can do with Fluent NHibernate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The NHibernate mapping you are looking for is `<any/>`.  Here are a few resources to help you get up to speed with this NHibernate mapping feature:

- [Ayende's blog post](http://ayende.com/blog/3966/nhibernate-mapping-any)
- [NHibernate documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-types-anymapping)
- [Fluent NHibernate documentation](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping#any)

I believe the *.hbm.xml that you are shooting for is something like this:

```
<class name="Recommendation" table="Recommendations">
  <id name="Id">
    <column name="Recommendation_Id" />
    <generator class="native"/>
  </id>

  <any name="RecommendedObject" id-type="System.Int32" meta-type="System.String">
    <meta-value value="M" class="Movie"/>
    <meta-value value="A" class="Actor"/>
    <meta-value value="D" class="Director"/>
    <column name="Object_Type"/>
    <column name="Object_Id"/>
  </any>

  <!-- other stuff ... -->
</class>
```

You should be able to accomplish that with Fluent NHibernate like so in Recommendation's mapping:

```
ReferencesAny(x => x.RecommendedObject)
    .IdentityType<int>()
    .EntityTypeColumn("Object_Type")
    .EntityIdentifierColumn("Object_Id")
    .AddMetaValue<Movie>("M")
    .AddMetaValue<Actor>("A")
    .AddMetaValue<Director>("D");
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT !!!! I've tested it and seems to work fine.
Seriously, a million thanks Daniel! :=)

Comment: Could you please show an example how to query over the `object RecommendedObject` with filtering by `Object_Id` ?

Comment: @Christian, are you referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940396/fluentnhibernate-referencesany-how-to-use-queryover-with-filter?