# NHibernate: Persist Reference to Interface with Multiple Contrete Classes

Tags: nhibernate

I have a 1-to-many relationship between the `RestorableEnvironment` and `IBaselineEntity` objects: a given `RestorableEnvironment` will have one and only one `IBaselineEntity`object, but each `IBaselineEntity` object may be tied to 0-n `RestorableEnvironment` objects. However, `IBaselineEntity` is implemented in one of two ways: via a file or via a database. My classes are (generally) like:

```
public interface IBaselineEntity
{
    BaselineImage BuildImage();
    //Remainder of interface
}

public class BaselineFile : IBaseline
{
    //implementation
}

public class BaselineDatabase : IBaseline
{
    //implementation
}

public class RestorableEnvironment
{
    public IBaselineEntity BaselineEntity { get; set; }
    //Remainder of class
}
```

NHibernate needs the concrete implementation of the `IBaselineEntity` in the references statement. To handle that, I have updated `RestorableEnvironment` to:

```
public class RestorableEnvironment
{
    public IBaselineEntity BaselineEntity
    {
        get { return BaselineDatabase ?? BaselineFile; }
        set
        {
            BaselineFile = value as BaselineFile;
            BaselineDatabase = value as BaselineDatabase;
        }
    }

    private BaselineFile _baselineFile;
    public BaselineFile BaselineFile
    {
        get { return _baselineFile; }
        protected set
        {
            _baselineFile = value;
            if (value != null)
                BaselineDatabase = null;
        }
    }

    private BaselineDatabase _baselineDatabase;
    public BaselineDatabase BaselineDatabase 
    {
        get { return _baselineDatabase; }
        protected set
        {
            _baselineDatabase= value;
            if (value != null)
                BaselineFile = null;
        }
    }

    // Remainder of class
}
```

Now that I have concrete classes, I can now map in NHibernate, but this feels like a hack. Are there any suggestions for an improvement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

map it as any reference

using fluentmapping

```
// ClassMap<RestorableEnvironment>
RestorableEnvironmentMap()
{
    ReferenceAny(e => e.BaselineEntity)
        .EntityIdentifierColumn("entirtyid")
        .EntityTypeColumn("entitytype")
        .IdentityType<int>()
        .MetaType<string>()
        .AddMetaValue<E1>("e1")
        .AddMetaValue<E2>("e2");
}
```

Comment: Perfect! For a little more on Meta Mappings, I also saw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989279/mapping-to-multiple-tables-with-fluent-nhibernate