# FluentNHibernate - ReferencesAny(), How to use QueryOver with filter?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I have an `UserAccount` class, which may belong to an `Employee` or a `Client`

I don't know how to QueryOver a `object OwnerRefObject` field, with a filter.

For Example:

```
public class UserAccount
{
   public virtual int Id {get;set;}
   public virtual string UserName {get;set;}
   public virtual string Password {get;set;}
   public virtual object OwnerRefObject {get;set;}
}

public class UserMap:ClassMap<User>
{
   public UserMap()
   {
      Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Indentity();
      Map(x => x.UserName);
      Map(x => x.Password);
      ReferencesAny(x => x.OwnerRefObject)
        .IdentityType<int>()
        .EntityTypeColumn("OwnerObject_Type")
        .EntityIdentifierColumn("OwnerObject_Id")
        .AddMetaValue<Client>(typeof(Client).Name)
        .AddMetaValue<Employee>(typeof(Employee).Name);
   }
}
```

#### Inside service:

```
public UserAccount GetClientUserAccountByClientId(int clientId)
{
   var result = _userAccountRepository
       .QueryOver()
       .Where(x => x.OwnerRefObject is Client)
        // Here I want something like (x => x.OwnerRefObject.Id==clientId)
       .Future()
       .FirstOrDefault();

   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two possible approaches that come to mind.  I am not free to test which of these would work at the moment.

- See if you can use `Restrictions.IdEq(object)` (in the `NHibernate.Criterion` namespace) so that you don't have to refer to the actual `Id` property, ...
- ... or you might try having `Client` and `Employee` implement an `IUserOwner` interface that has an `Id` property.

I hope I get a chance to come back and refine this answer when I have more time.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about an interface too.

Comment: @Christian What was your final solution? Did using the interface work or some other better method?